# how to format a float in a tab's space (<8 characters) in Python?

Tags: python, formatting

The intention is to print a table with `TAB` character. For this reason I need to restrict all fields to be < 8 characters.

I tried various format strings, none works

```
def test(format_string):
    print("\tFormat string is '%s'" % format_string)
    print(format_string % 0.12345678)
    print(format_string % 0.00012345678)
    print(format_string % 12.3456789)

test("\t%5g")
test("\t%5f")
test("\t%.5g")
test("\t%.5f")
test("\t%5.5g")
test("\t%5.5f")
```

What I wish to get is:

```
0.12346
0.00012
12.3457
```

Result (none of them always produce <8 characters):

```
Format string is '  %5g'
0.123457
0.000123457
12.3457
Format string is '  %5f'
0.123457
0.000123
12.345679
Format string is '  %.5g'
0.12346
0.00012346
12.346
Format string is '  %.5f'
0.12346
0.00012
12.34568
Format string is '  %5.5g'
0.12346
0.00012346
12.346
Format string is '  %5.5f'
0.12346
0.00012
12.34568
```

Comment: the problem is that any number > 99999999 does not fit in 8 chars. I'd guess it could be a reason why printf does not have an option for this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only way is to trim the number before formatting:

```
>>> "%.6g" % round(0.12345678,5)
'0.12346'
>>> "%.6g" % round(12.3456789,5)
'12.3457'
>>> "%.6g" % round(1234.56789,5)
'1234.57'
```